# Oracle Count even if nothing is there

Tags: sql, oracle, count

So i have this query:

```
SELECT p.*, d.reviews, TRUNC(ds.ratingAvg, 2) as ratingAvg
  FROM place p, 
    (SELECT pid,
      COUNT(rating) as ratings, 
      COUNT(review) as reviews
      FROM describes 
      GROUP BY pid) d,
    (SELECT pid, AVG(rating) as ratingAvg FROM describes GROUP BY pid) ds
  WHERE d.pid = p.pid AND d.pid = ds.pid
;
```

It will return stuff from place and then d is another table describes. It will get the number of reviews the place has and the average rating. This works perfectly fine as long as there is something in the describes table. How can i go about getting the stuff that does not have anything in describes as well. Basically 0 rating or 0 reviews.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coalesce()` and `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT p.*
     , coalesce(d.reviews, 0)     AS reviews
     , coalesce(ds.rating_avg, 0) AS rating_avg
FROM   place p
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT pid
   --   , COUNT(rating) AS ratings  -- unused?
        , count(review) AS reviews
   FROM   describes
   GROUP  BY pid
   ) d ON d.pid = p.pid
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT pid
        , trunc(avg(rating), 2) AS rating_avg
   FROM   describes
   GROUP  BY pid
   ) ds ON ds.pid = p.pid;
```

**Note** how I use `ON ds.pid = p.pid` in the second `JOIN` and not `ON ds.pid = d.pid` like you had.

If the third relation is left-joined to the second which in turn is left-joined to the first, you lose rows from the third relation if none can be found in the second. Doesn't make any difference in this particular case, because we have two unconditional queries on the same table - which should be simplified:

```sql
SELECT p.*
     , coalesce(d.reviews, 0)   AS reviews
     , coalesce(d.rating_avg, 0) AS rating_avg
FROM   place p
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT pid
   --   , COUNT(rating) AS ratings  -- unused?
        , count(review) AS reviews
        , trunc(avg(rating), 2) AS rating_avg
   FROM   describes
   GROUP  BY pid
   ) d ON d.pid = p.pid;
```

Comment: I like your simplified solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the implicit `INNER JOIN` by combining the results in the `WHERE` clause, you should use `LEFT JOINS`.

#### Using explicit JOIN

```
SELECT  p.*
        , d.reviews
        , TRUNC(ds.ratingAvg, 2) as ratingAvg
FROM    place p
        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT  pid
                  , COUNT(rating) as ratings
                  , COUNT(review) as reviews
          FROM    describes 
          GROUP BY 
                  pid
        ) d ON d.pid = p.pid
        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT  pid
                  , AVG(rating) as ratingAvg 
          FROM    describes 
          GROUP BY 
                  pid
        ) ds ON ds.pid = d.pid
```

[LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

> The result of a left outer join (or simply left join) for table A and
>   B always contains all records of the "left" table (A), even if the
>   join-condition does not find any matching record in the "right" table
>   (B). This means that if the ON clause matches 0 (zero) records in B,
>   the join will still return a row in the result—but with NULL in each
>   column from B.